# Getting values from database as in Array

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching data from database in array form. There are two raws in database. 1) groupID 2) groupname. And I used

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

I used this,

```
foreach($get_group as $key => $element){
        echo "$element";
}
```

In that case I am getting 'Array' as output everytime (depends on howmany elements are there)

I am not getting actual content of the array.

I tried by using $element[0] but no results..

Comment: Post the result of `print_r($get_group)`, it may help know the levels of the array.

Comment: Post the code where you get your sql data.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [groupID] => 1 [group] => Scripts ) [1] => Array ( [groupID] => 2 [group] => Adword Question ) [2] => Array ( [groupID] => 3 [group] => Stats Questions ) [3] => Array ( [groupID] => 4 [group] => Terms Questions ) [4] => Array ( [groupID] => 5 [group] => Platform Questions ) [5] => Array ( [groupID] => 6 [group] => Landing Page - Home Val Questions ) [6] => Array ( [groupID] => 7 [group] => Other ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get is actually an array of associative arrays.
And in your loop you are just iterating through the first one, so you get in $element an associative array and that's what you are trying to echo.

You need to access each field of the associative array separately. Something like.

```
foreach($get_group as $key => $element){
        echo "<br />groupID: ".$element["groupID"]." Group Name: ".$element["group"];
}
```

Or even better

```
foreach($get_group as $key => $element){
    foreach($element as $column_name=> $value){
             echo $column_name.": ".$value." ";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: If my array is like is: 

    Array ( [0] => Array ( [scriptQuestion] => Questio 1 [scriptAnswer] => Answer 1 ) [1] => Array ( [scriptQuestion] => Question 2 [scriptAnswer] => Answer 2 ) ) 

and I want to print only "Question 1" at a time. I want to print separately, because after that I will put it in the loop. Right now I am getting all the values of that array, like this
    (Questio 1    Answer 1     Question 2     Answer 2)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, this will print all questions without the answers.

     foreach($get_group as $key => $element){
             echo "<br />".$element["scriptQuestion"];
     }